# What is difference between Android and Android Rom?

Tags: android, android-source

I am new to AOSP anybody tell me what is difference between Android & Android Rom

I have found when i am googled but I did not understand the exact difference

Android is the open-source operating system used for smartphones.

Android ROM is the Android operating system. It is composed of a Linux kernel and various add-ons to achieve specific functionality.

Comment: "A stock ROM is the ROM that comes with a device; the device is "stocked" with that ROM by the manufacturer" And "An AOSP ROM is a ROM based on the Android Open Source Project. In the purest sense, AOSP refers to unmodified ROMs or code from Google."  Read This: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14628/whats-the-difference-between-an-aosp-rom-and-a-stock-rom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know:
**ROM**
Literally it stands for Read Only Memory. When people talking about ROM it`s referring to the phone's internal memory. The memory where your firmware/apps are stored. When people say, falshing a new ROM, it means they are flashing a new version of the firmware onto their phone.

**Android**
In this case they are referring to the OS or to the product of Google.
Brace your self, Obvious link coming:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)

Answer (score 0):

ROM is in fact "Read Only Memory." But for your purposes that has **nothing** to do with the use case here.  Early on with some hardware the operating system was stored on a specific chip, a ROM chip. What you flashed onto that chip is called "the ROM image." It had to be written with special purpose hardware, or it had to be written to in a special boot sequence (like with a DOS bootdisk).

With Android, we distribute images which usually overwrite a file system without formatting it or partitioning it. That's more of a sloppy and crappy install and it's likely to go away at some point in time when someone clever does it the same way a desktop runs. So an "Android ROM" is usually just like a zip archive that gets unzipped to `/`. That's a bad way to upgrade a computer, but it's how it's done for now. It's also more acceptable to do it in such a bad way because on phones upgrades are done so seldom. You may get an OTA upgrade once a month, or every other month. And, you likely upgrade your phone fewer than 10 times.